# I set up my wired D-Link modem in windows easily, but in ubuntu, it is a bloody job!

Tags: networking, internet, router, modem, d-link

I want to set up my wired ADSL2+ D-Link router. It is simply:

1. Typing `192.168.1.1` in address bar.
2. username and password
   [image]
3. In Ubuntu what appears is:
   [image]
   It needs clicking *refresh* bottom multiple times for the next window to appear:
   [image]
4. During set up through `Advanced Setup` menu, by pushing the botton **Next** in each step, the error above, namely **400 Bad Request** appears multiple times. Again I have to click *refresh* in order to go to the next step. It may take half an hour to reach the final step which re-starts the modem automatically.
   This all is in obvious contrast with what I experience in **Windows 10**. In windows, set up can be done easily and cleanly without any **400 Bad Request** error.

**Question**
What exactly the problem is?

**OS**: Ubuntu 18.04 , Windows 10
**Modem**: D-Link DSL-2520U

[image]
**Edit**
The output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; uname -a` is

```bsh
08:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Ralink corp. RT3090 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe [1814:3090]
    Subsystem: AzureWave RT3090 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe [1a3b:2041]
    Kernel driver in use: rt2800pci
    Kernel modules: rt2800pci
Linux soha 4.15.0-96-generic #97-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 1 03:25:46 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**Why did I re-set the router?**
Actually, I had no network whereas everything was seemed fine; I mean, when I was trying to go to a web page, this was appeared in that tab:
[image]
The gray circle which rotates counter clockwise for up to 3 minutes; Then it depended on chance; the page might finally open or not. I called to the provider and they said "we see no problem in our side"; The modem also showed no indication of a problem; DSL and internet lights were ON. As I saw no solution, I re-set the modem.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; uname -a` terminal command. Are you sure the cable is OK?

Comment: After you configured the modem, does the network connrction work well?

Comment: There is no problem with the cable; and yes, the network works well after configuration. As a more detailed story, I pushed a pin into the reset hole on the back of the router. Then trying to set it up was unsuccessful in *ubuntu* whereas it was neatly successful in *windows*, BTW I use a dual-boot laptop. This situation has been repeated multiple times in the past. Sometimes that I am sufficiently patient, I can get the job done in *ubuntu* with trying **refresh** button a lot of times.

Comment: After resetting the modem in *windows*, I came back to *Ubuntu*; Now network works well, i.e. I surf the web smoothly; but if I try to go to `192.168.1.1` in ubuntu, **400 Bad Request** still exists.

Comment: This is a mystery to me.

Comment: Sometimes I need to use VPN; It seems that my problem may relate to using VPN; I mean, after disconnecting VPN, some side effects may reside and don't disappear. I don't know but it is probable that these effects are the origin of the problem...